# How to import python file from folder

Tags: python

I would like to import the config file. it from sub-directory

```sh
├── config
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── database.ini
│   └── log.py
├── main.py
```

config.py

```py
def function(file='database.ini',section='sql'):
   return
```

database.ini

```sh
[sql] 
host=1.1.1.1
user=admin
password=admin
database=sql
```

main.py

```py
from config.config import function

def Run(): 
    Test = function()    

if __name__=="__main__":
   Run()
```

The error warning look like
"Section sql not found in the database.ini file"

Now you see the structure of project.
How to fix this?

Comment: This cannot be what you are executing `def function(file=database.ini,section='sql'):`would yield `NameError: name 'database' is not defined`. There must be some code trying to open database.ini

Comment: filename as string maybe? `file='database.ini'` Anyway, the error described in the questions suggests a different problem. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012337/python-config-parser-cant-find-section) is helpful?

Comment: This code it's work when i move main.py into the config/ folder. So i guess the problem it's from path/directory.

Comment: try `def function(file='./config/database.ini',section='sql'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the root directory in a python project set by default where your main is.
In your case your try to acces `./database.ini` but from your root folder (where main.py is) this file is at `./config/database.ini`
To fix your code change this line

```py
def function(file='database.ini',section='sql'):
    pass
```

by this line

```py
def function(file='./config/database.ini',section='sql'):
    pass
```